# Insert zeroes into multidimensional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a bing_stats table that has records holding various daily stats from online campaigns like so:

`user_id: "5", date: "20140306", conversions: ["0", "0", "1", "0"], spend: ["2.83", "0.45", "33.74", "0.00"], clicks: ["2", "1", "10", "0"], campaign_name: ["Seattle", "LA", "Houston", "DC"]>`

A user inputs a date range in the view that pulls the records.  Every once and a while a user may have paused a few of their campaigns through Bing and that will cause their daily record to look like this:

`user_id: "5", date: "20140306", conversions: ["0"], spend: ["2.83"], clicks: ["2"], campaign_name: ["Seattle"]>`

Its causing an issue when I try to sum all the records within the date range

```
click_arrays = bing_records.map {|record| record.clicks}
@combined_clicks = click_arrays.map{|i| i.map{|s| s.to_i}}.transpose.map(&:sum)

=>Element size differs (1 should be 4)
```

To solve this I'm attempting to first determine the length of the largest array in the given set.  Then insert zero in place of the missing elements.

```
click_arrays = bing_records.map {|record| record.clicks}
=> [["2", "1", "10", "0"], ["0", "2", "7", "0"], ["0", "1", "4", "0"], ["8"], ["1", "2", "12", "0"], ["1", "2", "14", "1"], ["1", "6", "11", "0"]]

click_arrays.min.count
=> 4

length = click_arrays.min.count
click_arrays.map {|n| n.in_groups_of(length, 0) {|g| p g}}
```

While doing that in an irb console I get what I want

```
=> ["2", "1", "10", "0"]["0", "2", "7", "0"]["0", "1", "4", "0"]["8", 0, 0, 0]["1", "2", "12", "0"]["1", "2", "14", "1"]["1", "6", "11", "0"]
```

But in the rails app I get a undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

```
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

Trace

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass:
app/controllers/adwordscampaign_controller.rb:56:in block in index
app/controllers/adwordscampaign_controller.rb:56:in index
(gem) actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in send_action
(gem) actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in process_action
(gem) actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
(gem) actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
(gem) activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in       `_run__590333479__process_action__708665489__callbacks'
(gem) activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
(gem) activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
(gem) activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
(gem) actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
```

Comment: why not giving the full error stack. It is much easy to understand and locate the error. Please give it

Comment: Does that give you what you needed @ArupRakshit?

Comment: Not a direct answer but how about establishing direct models like user has many campaigns, campaign has many daily_records. You process the data upon receipt, push them to correct models, and then all queries and calculations are based on those models? I think that would make life much easier, comparing with pulling hair on those unstable arrays.

Comment: What @BillyChan said with the addition that you should be doing your summary calculations inside the database. Fix your data model and let the database do its job. And BTW, that's not a multi-dimensional array, Ruby doesn't have those (unless you count Matrix I suppose), that's just an array-of-arrays.

Comment: @BillyChan, thank you for the response.  There are other considerations regarding the app that make that tough (would've posted them but was told on SO to keep it short - "what I'm getting, what I'm trying to get") but I will def take another look at the models with an eye for associations.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @muistooshort.  I was describing an array of arrays on here before and someone corrected me calling it a multidimensional array so next time I'll know :)

Comment: So, what's on line 56 in adwordscampain_controller.rb? And which of the lines from your irb session does it correspond with?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't specify for which method you're getting your Undefined Method error, I'm going to guess that the method is `count`. Here what I think happens in the Rails app:

One of the records has a value of `nil` for the `clicks` attribute. This means `click_arrays.min` returns `nil`. Then `nil.count` gives you the error.

So, you should not use `#min` to get the longest element of `click_arrays`. Please note it's broken even without the problem of `nil`:

```
[["1", "2"], ["3"]].min
=> ["1", "2"]`
[["3", "2"], ["1"]].min 
=> ["1"]
```

Instead, I recommend something like this:

```
click_lengths = bing_records.map {|record| record.clicks.try(:count) || 0}
length = click_lengths.max
```

Going a little further, I think you should be aware that this will only give the correct results if the disabled campains are always at the end of the list. In your example, this would work if the second record says `["Seattle"]` or `["Seattle", "LA", "Houston", "DC"]`, but not for `["LA", "Houston"]`. In that case, the numbers won't line up correcly.

Comment: Thank you for the better way to grab that length @Matijs.  My apologies for leaving out the method.  I've updated it.